# Get all textblock's property value on click wp8

Tags: c#, properties, windows-phone-8

quick question,

(im using visual studio 2012/ windows phone 8 application)

how can i get the properties of a textblock on its tap event?
i have the tap event :

```
void item_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
    {
        var control = (sender as TextBlock);

        MessageBox.Show(control.Text + ", was tapped!", "Happyness", MessageBoxButton.OK);
    }
```

i get most of the properties, but the ones i want i dont get, i would like to see what is that textblock's "Grid.Row" property? is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ah i found it! hopes this help other people aswell,
all i did was :

```
 var myrow = control.GetValue(Grid.RowProperty);
```

and the result was  = 1;

have a good one!